# where to set default value of session variables

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have an older .NET 4.6 project that uses web forms.

I have a Session variable that I use to track if a user is logged in securely or not.

After a user logs in using a login form and after a few security checks, I set it like this in a class that all other classes inherit from:

```
Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IsSecure") = True
```

However, I want this to be set to False as default.  Should I place it in the Global.asax.vb file in the Application_Start method like this?

```
Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IsSecure") = False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Application_Start is for when the application starts - so I doubt there's even an HttpContext available at that point. [This article](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/126/aspnet-global-asax-events-methods) goes into more detail about those methods.

Comment: @mason oh ok, thanks! I didn't know that.  Thanks for the article link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session_Start is good place in Global.asax to set default value.

```
public void Session_Start()
{
    Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("IsSecure") = False
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Session is not a method so you must use [] as shown below:

Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSecure"] = False

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The question is about VB.NET code, and in VB you use `()` for key/index access in dictionary and array like objects where in C# you use `[]` as you put in your answer.